# PySpark Multiple column changes using one statement?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

Basically I have a DataFrame which has around 80 columns and I need to change the rows on the fly for approx(10-15) rows based on some case statements. I am using `df.WithColumn` method to make the changes. However, it becomes very costly as I need to call those case statements 10-15 times( From what I understand, It will loop through the whole df 15 times). How can I improve it such that for each row in a `df`, `df.withcolumn` is executed? That way I can add 15 case statements for each row of the df and it won't be that costly. Or please suggest an alternative.

```
    df.withColumn('FY',F.when(df['ID'].substr(5,2).isin({'11','12'}),
      df['ID'].substr(1,4).cast("integer") + 1).
      otherwise(df['ID'].substr(1,4)).cast("integer"))



.
.
.
.
.
.
.

    df.withColumn('FY1',F.when(df['ID1'].substr(5,2).isin({'11','12'}),
      df['ID'].substr(1,4).cast("integer") + 1).
      otherwise(df['ID1'].substr(1,4)).cast("integer"))
```